# Is there a Firefox equivalent to Chrome's "translateZ(0);" to force GPU accelerated CSS animation?

Tags: firefox, css, css-transitions

I have a CSS3 transition which is smooth as silk in Chrome, but choppy in (the latest version of) Firefox

I know that I can force GPU acceleration on a DOM object in Chrome by setting **-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);** on it

Is there an equivalent style I can add to force GPU acceleration in Firefox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firefox GPU-accelerates by default when it can.  So there's nothing to "force" GPU acceleration: if it's possible, it's already done.

Comment: when i use animations in Firefox it can get to 100% CPU.. I think the whole hardware accelerate thing is not working well in Gecko

Comment: It really depends on your hardware. OS, drivers, and the like...  But yes, there are cases that Gecko doesn't accelerate that WebKit does, and vice versa.

Comment: I have a machine with 16GB RAM, SSD and 4 CORE CPU, with a good graphic card, and still a bunch of simple animation crank it up..

Comment: Which OS?  Does about:support say anything useful in the graphics section?

Comment: windows7. anything useful? my graphic card is ATI Radeon HD 4300, but even so, a mighty GPU should handle simple animations tasks done 15 years ago in computer games..

Comment: Anything useful like whether your drivers are being blacklisted, say.  But again, not all animations are done on the GPU yet.  Some are, some are not.

Comment: it happens on all the office computers, MAC/windows..its all CPU consuming as hell. sure I still use css animation, but this, it's lame rich browser vendors don't pay their workers enough to fix this shit ASAP. hire more men i don't care, get me to the future already, present web is shit.