# jQuery animation performance

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Sometimes jQuery animations of elements seem to perform worse (fps-wise) than other elements. 
A very simple example would be if you have a very complicated DOM that you are trying to move around vs a very simple DOM.

Are there any lesser-known rules that greatly affect the performance of your animations, but might be easy to omit?

Comment: Can you post an example of this?

Comment: Some good info here: http://jankfree.org (chrome devteam)

Comment: @dc5 that post is gold. Thanks. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Some more good infos: http://learn.jquery.com/performance/

Comment: For other people having specific issues with Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068132/why-arent-browsers-smart-enough-to-hardware-accelerate-without-tricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some great information about browser performance at [jankfree.org](http://jankfree.org)