# Android Internet Browser Performance

Tags: android, performance, browser

I'm finding that using transitions of any kind in the default "Internet" browser on android devices is painful. The performance is appalling, whether it's javascript or CSS transitions. It's not the device as Chrome performs exceptionally.

Is there any kind of hack to force the Android Internet browser to perform as expected, with hardware acceleration, or is it the IE of mobile browsers and we're all doomed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default browser to another like Firefox or Chrome.

In newer versions of Android, Chrome is the default browser.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/47617

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that but it doesn't solve the problem for those using older versions.

Comment: You can do a trick to force WebKit-browsers to use hardware acceleration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068132/why-arent-browsers-smart-enough-to-hardware-accelerate-without-tricks